# how to render sql with colon named parameters

Tags: java, property-placeholder

I have a sql like `insert into USER(NAME,AGE) VALUES(:NAME,:AGE)`
and I have an object like User(name='gggg',age=10)

how to render the sql get the result like `insert into USER(NAME,AGE) VALUES('ggg',10)`